# Real world examples of variables

Tags: variables, language-agnostic

I'm gonna teach kids computer programming.
I'm gonna teach the children about variables.

I want to tell the subject through real life examples to better understand the variables, but there is no example in my mind.

How do you teach variables to a child?

Can you give examples by making real life similes for children to understand the subject of variables?

Comment: It may be easier to start off with the concept of parameters -- variables are not strictly a necessary concept, and purely functional languages do without them entirely. But anyone can understand `print "Hello, <your-name-here>"` and then start thinking about how we might fill in `your-name-here`, and what would happen if we changed it. If you want that as a real life example, just bring along one of those "Hello, my name is ___" badges and make it reusable with stickers.

Comment: So it's not appropriate.I fixed the question to make it clearer.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by *variable*. There are two closely related things here: the first is the idea of being able to refer to different things with one general name, as a label. Almost anyone understands this as part of language; real life examples are readily found ("when someone walks into the room, shake their hand"). The second is the idea of a container that can hold different, modifiable values. This has no obvious real life counterpart I can think of; most tutorials I've seen go for the classic "box that I take things out of and put new things in" model...

Comment: ...and that works as a *model* of how a variable works, but is not necessarily "natural" in the sense that most of us do not deal with boxes like that in our daily lives. (Doesn't make it a bad way to explain variables in a program, which are for the most part also not like things we encounter in our daily lives.)

Comment: "box that I take things out of and put new things in" model.Can be a good example

Comment: If you consider that a good example, try playing *[Human Resource Machine](https://tomorrowcorporation.com/humanresourcemachine)*. The connection to "real life" is tenuously made by representing the CPU as a little office worker that you direct.

Comment: Well, I'm going to check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpiest example I can think of, is the calculation of the sum of all numbers from 1 to `n`, where `n` is a number the user can enter. It gives the following piece of pseudo-code:

```
int input_number, counter, sum;
string output_sum;

show_on_screen("Enter a natural number: ");
get_input(input_number);
sum = 0;
for (counter = 1 to input_number):
  sum = sum + counter;
next counter;

output_sum = convert_number_to_string(sum);
show_on_screen("The sum equals " + output_sum);
```

This example contains following items:

- variables and their types (why the difference between `integer` and `string`)
- using variables as placeholders
- using meaningful names for variables
- using variables as counters (for-loop, you can also use a while-loop, and explain the similarities, differences)

Good luck

Comment: I would like to describe it by simulating real life examples rather than programming.So it's not appropriate.I fixed the question to make it clearer.